# Flex advanced datagrid styling

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, adobe, advanceddatagrid

I'm using an advanced datagrid in a system I'm building.

the design PSD from the designer includes a special background on rollover.

So, I need the background of the cells in a row to get the background from an image, only when the mouse rolls over a specific row.

is this even possible?

can a row get the background from an image (CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method available in DataGrids (and Lists) called drawRowBackgrounds() that is responsible for drawing a simple highlight into a row in response to a user interaction. You might be able to accomplish the design in the PSD programmatically by using the Flash drawing API. If you need to use an image asset, you could try to add it as a child of the Sprite that is passed as the first argument of this method call.