# How to wiperight or wipeleft using on each row of datagrid using flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I am a new of flex , i have four columns and five rows of datagrid . i want know how to add color overlay of wipeleft or wiperight on each row of datagrid. when i click which row then i got that wipe action.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get those "wipeleft or wiperight" events than you just need to use drawRowBackgrounds() method as mentioned in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245650/flex-advanced-datagrid-styling/2258520#2258520).